# java.lang.VerifyError: reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClientConfig overrides final method connectionProvider

Tags: java, reactor-netty

Getting "reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClientConfig overrides final method connectionProvider" when upgrading the reactor-netty-http version from 1.0.19 to 1.0.24.

using code :
**

```
@Mock
private WebClient webClient;

@Before
public void setup() {
    webClient = WebClient.builder().baseUrl("baseurl").build(); -- > line giving error
}
```

**

what to change to write these tests using version1.0.24

Comment: Do you have both `reactor-netty-core` and `reactor-netty-http` with version 1.0.24?

Comment: I did not add reactor-netty-core. After adding it the error got resolved.
Thankyou!!